# How to automate command prompt command in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, batch-file

I am using the below command to load performance counters into SQL Server database.

```
C:\Users\w8>TYPEPERF -f SQL -s admin -cf "C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt" -si 15 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4
```

I have a requirement to schedule it for every 15 mins to collect the counters.
I am guessing if we can make it as batch file then I can schedule it using task scheduler but i am new to batch files concept.

Can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since this is for SQL Server I suggest you use SQL Agent instead of windows scheduler.

In *SQL Server Management Studio*, open out *SQL Server Agent*, right click on *jobs* and create a new job.

Now create a new step of type *Operating system (cmdexec)* and simply paste that in:

```
TYPEPERF -f SQL -s admin -cf "C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt" -si 15 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4
```

You do need to make sure that TYPEPERF is installed on the SQL Server and you might need to run it in a certain folder. You also need to ensure the SQL Agent account has access. None of these are different in windows scheduler though.

Use of a batch file is optional. If the command was any more complex it might be worth it.

Your job (since it can run unattended) needs to run as *somebody* so it knows if it's allowed to do things, and can tell various logs who it is etc. At the moment it is running as the default 'somebody', (NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT), which it turns out doesn't have rights to create a file. So you need to run it as somebody who can.

Any of the things listed below can be done to give it required rights. Some of these are plain silly and some may or may not be appropriate for your situation.

- Create a special service account and use that
- Add `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` to local admin
- Find the folder and give `NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT` create rights in there
- Create a SQL Server credential of yourself and use that in the job
- Change SQL Agent to run as yourself

The first option is the most 'Entperprise' but probably over the top for your needs.

The last option is easier but suffers if you have to change your password.

I'll explain the last option:

1. Open Services manager by running services.msc (or typing services into search)
2. Find `SQL Server Agent` in the list
3. Double click it, go to the `Log On` tab and enter your login/password there
4. Press OK (you might get a message about log on as a service right)

Now your SQL Agent will run as you and you shouldn't get that message anymore.

Comment: Thanks Nick for your help on this. I have schedule this job on my laptop but got the below error. Message
Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Exiting, please wait...                             Error:  Unable to create the specified log file.  Process Exit Code -1073738807.  The step failed.  Job step contains TYPEPERF -f SQL -s admin -cf "C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt" -si 15
 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4

Comment: I'll add more info

Comment: I added a bunch of info. Are you in an 'enterprise environment' i.e. you have a IT support team, or you in a smaller situation with 0 or 1 people in your IT team?

Comment: Not a big fan or terminating your sentences with a period, are you :).

Comment: I'm so used to ending them in question marks, I forgot :)

Answer (score 0):

A batch file is effectively whatever commands you'd type into `cmd`.

There are a few differences, but mainly control issues - looping and so on.

If that `typeperf` command is the only one you need, then just exactly that line should suffice.

You can decorate it a little. Depends on taste

```
@echo off
setlocal
typeperf...
cls
exit
```

where `@` at the start of a command disables command-echoing for that command.
`echo off` turns command echoing off until the batch ends
`setlocal` ensures any environment changes made are temporary
`cls` clears the `cmd` window
`exit forcibly exits batch.

Just need to place it in a file named *whateveryoulikebutdontuseacommandkeyword*.bat

use a text-editor but not a word-processor. Notepad is barely adequate as it tends to try to format the text entered. Ensure the file is saved as ASCII.

Comment: Thanks Magoo for your prompt response.I tried this by saving the name as counters.bat but no luck.@echo off
setlocal
C:\Users\w8>TYPEPERF -f SQL -s admin -cf "C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt" -si 15
 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4
cls
exit              . Please help me.

Comment: Best to `edit` your code into your question as additional data. Cut-and-paste, then select the code section and press `{}` to highlight (easier than inserting 4 leading spaces). It's impossible to see **exactly** what code you'e using from a comment - but the glaring problem is the `>` before `typeperf`. The newlines should be exactly as shown. batch is an old language and doesn't agree well with free-format.

Comment: Actually, the `C:\Users\w8>` is out-of-place. Batch prompts with the current directoryname by default to say "what next?"

Comment: I have tried by removing c:\users\w8> also. now my batch  will will looks {@echo on
setlocal
TYPEPERF -f SQL -s admin -cf "C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt" -si 15
 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4
cls
exit}

Comment: If you insert a `pause` line just before the `cls` line, then the batch will pause and you'll be able to see any messages produced by the system.

Comment: Thanks Magoo. My batch file is working now. The issues is actual command is in multiple line so I have made it as single line and worked fine.Now the challange is how to call this batch file in sqlserver agent ?

Comment: I am succedded in making this command in batch file.but when I Called this batch file in sqlserver agent i got the error { Executed as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. C:\Windows\system32>TYPEPERF -f SQL -s admin -cf "C:\CounterCollect\Counters.txt" -si 15 -o SQL:SQLServerDS!log1 -sc 4  Exiting, please wait...                           Unknown.  Process Exit Code -1073738783.  The step failed. }

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `typeperf`. I'd suggest the significant factors are `Executed as user` and `C:\Windows\system32>` which may indicate the current directory in which the process is being executed is `C:\Windows\system32` which possibly isn't where required files reside. Perhaps you should execute `cd c:\users\w8` before the `typeperf` line to switch to the directory you were using for the works-from-the-prompt version. As for the user problem, perhaps that user isn't authorised to run the executable or access the files. Perhaps you need to schedule the job to process under a different user

Comment: @Magoo is completely right and I've added more info to my answer explaining what needs to be done.